# Save data to local storage using Room

Tags: kotlin, save, android-room

I apologize in advance if the question seems incomprehensible, since android development and kotlin are not my main stack. I will try to explain in as clear a language as possible.

I have a class that is responsible for intercepting data from HTTP-request. This implementation reflects the following code

```
    class PocketScoutInterceptor() : Interceptor {


    fun buildPacket(timestamp: Long, duration: Double, request: Request, response: Response) {
        val reqBody = request.body
        val respBody = response.body?.string()

        val packet = Packet(
            id = 0,
            userId = PocketScoutConfig.userId,
            deviceId = PocketScoutConfig.deviceId,
            sessionId = PocketScoutConfig.sessionId,
            timestamp = timestamp,
            duration = duration.roundToInt(),
            protocol = "http",
            request = room.entities.Request(
                request_method = request.method,
                request_url = request.url.toUrl().toString(),
                request_headers = request.headers.toMultimap() as Mapping,
                request_body = (reqBody?.toString() ?: ""),
                request_size = (reqBody?.toString()?.length ?: 0),
            ),
            room.entities.Response(
                response_code = response.code,
                response_headers = response.headers.toMultimap() as Mapping,
                response_body = (respBody ?: ""),
                response_size = (respBody?.length ?: 0),
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Further, I need to save this data in a local database, I chose room.

Next I created a database class

```
    @TypeConverters(value = [RoomTypeConverters::class])
@Database(
    version = 1,
    entities = [Packet::class],
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class NetworkDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun packetDao(): PacketDao
}
```

I just have to learn how to save data in local storage. I've watched several videos on this topic and read the documentation several times, but as far as my example is concerned, I can't find an answer. Maybe you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1).** You need to build the database via the Room `databaseBuilder` function/method. The following change to the @Database annotated class would do this and would return a singleton:-

```
@TypeConverters(value = [RoomTypeConverters::class])
@Database(entities = [Packet::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class NetworkDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun packetDao(): PacketDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: NetworkDatabase? = null;
        fun getInstance(context: Context): NetworkDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,NetworkDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity/convenience but shouldn't really run stuff on the main thread */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as NetworkDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- Note ideally you would access the database off the main thread. However the above allows the database access to be via the main thread and thus easier to demonstrate.

**2).** The next stage is to actually **use the above**, as an example consider the following activity code (working example):-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: NetworkDatabase
    lateinit var dao: PacketDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        /* Get an instance of NetworkDatabase  and the packetDao */
        db = NetworkDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.packetDao()

        /* add some data (1 row)*/
        val m1 = Mapping(header = mapOf())
        dao.add(
            Packet(
                id = 10,
                deviceId =
                "device10",
                sessionId = "session100",
                timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis(),
                protocol = "HTML",
                request = Request(requestMethod = "the method", requestUrl = "blah", requestHeaders = m1,
                    requestBody = "ReqBody", requestSize = 10),
                userId = "userxxx",
                duration = 200,
                response = Response(100,m1,"RspBody",210)
        )
        )
        /* Extract all rows and write to the log */
        for(p in dao.getAll()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Packet ID is ${p.id} DeviceId is ${p.deviceId} Duration is ${p.duration} ....")
        }
    }
}
```

The above, when run (for the first time) results in the log containing :-

```
D/DBINFO: Packet ID is 10 DeviceId is device10 Duration is 200 ....
```

Obviously you would build the Packet(s) via your Interceptor

Comment: I have  @Entity(tableName = "packets") before data class Packet

Comment: Or did I misunderstand your first sentence?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe you can tell me how to adapt your code in point three to my code in the PocketScoutInterceptor class. Since I have data saved from this class and not from MainActivity. I'm trying to do something similar to your code, but I get an error in db = NetworkDatabase.getInstance(this) : Type mismatch.
Required:
Context
Found:
PocketScoutInterceptor

Comment: @Павел **this** needs to be a context, typically obtained via an activity (this is because the databaseBuilder requires a context (used to ascertain the location of the database file)). There are ways to get the Context from anywhere e.g. https://www.dev2qa.com/android-get-application-context-from-anywhere-example/

Comment: I thank you for your help. But I still haven't fully figured out how to apply it correctly in my case. If you have time and desire, please help me to finalize this question.